# qtip unable to display Tool Tip

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In aspx page inside `head` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    InitializeToolTips();
  });

  function InitializeToolTips() {
    $.toolTipRequest("txtText", "Text tip");
    $.toolTipRequest("imgGirl", "You want to see image");

  }
  (function($) {
    $.toolTipRequest = function(id, data) {
      $('#' + id).qtip({
        content: {
          data: {
            id: data
          }

        },
        position: {
          corner: {
            target: 'leftBottom',
            tooltip: 'topLeft'
          }
        },
        style: {
          name: 'blue'
        }
      });
    }

  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Code run and didn't show any error in console but I am unable to display message(Tool tip).What is my mistake. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution.

Instead of:

```
content: { data: { id: data }},
```

Using:

```
 content: { text: data },
```

Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you're trying to call on a specific id. Usually, I have trouble when I try to call one if I put my jQuery before the div. Try moving your javascript from the head to the end of the html. I don't know if that'll help but, it's worth a shot, right?